# ComboBox with Arrow / Symbol only

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles

I'd like to have a combobox that is really small in width and displays only the arrow. Background is to save space beside other buttons in the layout, and not visualize the selected item. But the dropdown should not be limited in width. I didnt find any properties to hide the inner textbox. Is it possible ?

Comment: Set the width to 20, the Dropdown should take as much space as it needs.

Comment: I didn't mention that I use a MSDN ComboBox Style. The ContentPresenter that displays the text starts at Margin 8, so it displays the selected text on top of the arrow, if the width is > 8.

Comment: I need to figure out if i can hide the ContentPresenter (Name="ContentSite"), and use this style anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ContentPresenter`, you could set the `Visibility` depending on the `ActualWidth` of the `ComboBox`:

```
<ContentPresenter Visibility={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=WidthToVisibility}}
```

In your `Converter`, you check if the value is 8 or less, then return `Visibility.Collapsed`, else return `Visibility.Visible`.